# Pass form validation value to php

Tags: php, javascript, forms, variables

So i have a simple form with a script to check the data before it submits:

```
<form action='self.php' name='my_form' method='post' onSubmit="return checkit();">
    <select name='menu' id='menu'>
        <option value='00'>ZERO</option>
        <option value='01'>ONE</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I want to have a pop up or alert box to request more information. Kinda like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkit()
{
    if(document.my_form.menu.value == "01")
    {
        var getColor = prompt("Enter Color: ", "enter the color");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

How would I then pass the variable "getColor" to a PHP variable on submit?

Almost something like:

```
<?php
    $theColorIs = getColor;
?>
```

Is there a way to do this? I know that PHP is server side and the script isn't, but the form has not been submitted because the script halts it. It seems like a simple thing to do, is there another option?

Thanks early for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hidden fields in your form to store the value and retrieve it through PHP

the html form:

```
<form action='self.php' name='my_form' method='post' onSubmit="return checkit();">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="myhiddenfield" id="myhiddenfield" />
<select name='menu' id='menu'>
<option value='00'>ZERO</option>
<option value='01'>ONE</option>
</select>
</form>
```

the script:

```
if(document.my_form.menu.value == "01")
{
   var getColor = prompt("Enter Color: ", "enter the color");
   document.getElementById('myhiddenfield').value = getColor;
}
```

So when the form is submitted, the value is stored in $_POST['myhiddenfield']

Comment: actually you don't need all this complication since when the form is submitted the value will be stored in  **$_POST['menu']**

Comment: if you read the question, he was not looking for menu **from the prompt**, he wanted to get a value, may be not part of menu items, and submit along with the form. Or am I missing something

Comment: from the prompt ? what do you mean by that ?

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, as this method is perfectly acceptable. The hidden input field acts as a place holder to which receives the color value, dynamaically, from the user input thanks to the JavaScript snippet above. This color value can then be passed along your script on submit and accessed via `$_POST['myhiddenfield']` though you may want to name your hidden input field more intuitively.

Comment: I assume that if I wanted two values, I would just use two separate hidden fields? (And of course two separate prompts...)

Comment: Yes. But why would you do that? It's obstructive and not recommended. There are better html-based approach - dialog based on html/css/jquery that can be used to collect multiple values at a time.

Comment: Im ok with one value. But would the value of the hidden field be submitted at the same time as 'menu' ? It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Then you may have to use javascript to submit the form after assigning the value `document.forms['my_form'].submit();`

Comment: I got it. I used the above example, which leaves out the id. getElementById , but the hidden value only had name= not id= .

Comment: Welcome. Sorry I omitted the Id, have added it.

Answer (score 0):

You could append the value to the query string of the form's action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkit()
{
  if(document.my_form.menu.value == "01")
  {
    var getColor = prompt("Enter Color: ", "enter the color");
    document.my_form.action += "?color=" + getColor;
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Then, you can reference the color in your PHP code, like so:

```
if( isset( $_GET['color'] )
{
  $theColorIs = $_GET['color'];
}
```